# Sort an array of strings as integers but there can be a non integer value

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, sorting

```
1
12
9
11
Some other String
13
22
```

So given the above `String[]` I want to sort it as if they were integers.
If I didn't have to deal with the random occurrence of a non int value then I would just use:

```
string[] SortedArray = UnsortedArray.OrderBy(o => int.Parse(o)).ToArray();
```

However this will exception once it reaches the `Some other String`

Any ideas?

Comment: Where would the string values come in the order and would they have to be ordered alphabetically?

Comment: I don't really care how the string values are sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
string[] SortedArray = UnsortedArray
    .OrderBy(z => 
    {
        int tmp;
        if (int.TryParse(z, out tmp))   // Take care of culture
        {
            return tmp;
        }

        return int.MinValue;    // Or MaxValue depending if non-numbers should
                                // be first or last
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Bingo thanks. Ill mark it as accepted once the timer runs down.